# legend scale of heatmap

Tags: r, legend, heatmap

I have a following table:

```
Samples      Mean1  Mean2 Diff
   A          125    250    2
   B          100    200    2
   C          150     75   -2
   D          50     150   -3
```

Now I want to generate a heatmap where the color code blocks should represent mean values while the legend should represents the maximum and minimum value of column "Diff" with respect to the mean values in heatmap...I tried pheatmap package in R but the legend comes purely based on the mean values i.e the maximum value is 250 and the minimum value is 50 but I want with respect to corresponding values in Diff Column i.e  the minimum value is -3 and the maximum value is 2..

Can Anyone assist me

Comment: Can you include `dput(head(df))` where `df` is your data, and then include the code you've tried for the heatmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I understood correctly, you want the color of the cells (and the legend) to represent the "DIFF" column values? And you want to display the mean values in the cells?

For example as shown in the screenshot below?

[image]

You can use the `cellnote` parameter in `heatmap.2()` (`gplots` package) to do this. 
The cellnote values are independent from the values that you used to "color" your cells.